# Listview Scrolling fires selectionChanged event occasionally

Tags: wpf, listview

I have a listview in my WPF application. While scrolling the listview items, sometimes the listview selection change event gets fired. This happens occassionally and not always. How do I prevent this? Initially I thought, my way of scrolling was too hard, that it fires the selection change event. But that's not the case.

Comment: While scrolling the listviewItems, Occasionally SelectionChanged Event is Firing... How can i fix this?

Comment: The item on which i touched first getting selected. That should not happen.

Comment: Are you `virtualizing`?

Comment: no, i am not virtualizing.